# Composite primary key duplicate insert error despite reported value not existing

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am getting a duplicate key insertion error when using `INSERT INTO` on a table with a composite primary key (`datetime, bigint`). I can't figure out why though because the reported error value doesn't exist in either the source CSV file that I `BULK INSERTED`, or the table that I'm inserting the modified CSV data into.  Here's what the error says:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure IT_Data.dbo.sp_ImportDriveAuditData, Line 80 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pkTimeQualifier'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DriveAuditData'. The duplicate key value is (Mar  5 2020 12:00AM, 1192400537322090213).

The only value in the table with that same uniquequalifier has a datetime 2020-03-05 00:00:01.730.  This is the same in the source CSV.

```
time                        uniqueQualifier
------------------------------------------------
2020-03-05 00:00:01.730     1192400537322090213
```

How could SQL Server be throwing this error, despite the insert not containing the specified composite key of (Mar  5 2020 12:00AM, 1192400537322090213) and the uniqueQualifier being entirely unique and unused a second time?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure there are no duplicates in your csv?  With SQL server, what it calls out isn't always the problem.  You should be able to open your CSV in excel and validate that there are no duplicate values.

Also, could you show your insert statement?  *You could be truncing your inserted values making them duplicate.*